# Multiple find and replace in MS Word from a list in MS Excel: code does not work for embedded tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to replace around 1000 words/phrases in Word from Excel string (column A by column B).
I am using the code below. It works well for a plain text, but does not work for tables embedded in the Word file: if the word to be replaced is in the table, the code replaces this word and creates many raws in the table not replacing all other words. How could I fix it? Thanks.

```
Sub findandreplace()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlWS As Object

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH TO EXCEL FILE")
Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Replace String with your Worksheet Name

lastRow = 1000

For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Words.Count - 1 Step 1
For j = 1 To lastRow Step 1
        ThisDocument.Words(i) = Replace(ThisDocument.Words(i), xlWS.Cells(j, 1).Value, xlWS.Cells(j, 2).Value)
    Next j
Next i

Set xlWS = Nothing
xlWB.Close True
Set xlWB = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code working for all words which in Word are: text words, commas, dots, paragraph marks, end of cell marks and many others. You should try to use `Find...Replace` feature instead. But if you want to stay with your code the quickes idea I could think of would be to add additional `If Statement` like this:

```
....
For j = 1 To lastRow Step 1
    If InStr(1, ThisDocument.Words(i), xlWS.Cells(j, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ThisDocument.Words(i) = Replace(ThisDocument.Words(i), xlWS.Cells(j, 1).Value, xlWS.Cells(j, 2).Value)
    End if
Next j
....
```

Comment: Kazimierz Jawor, thank you for your suggestion. What would be the code if I use Find...Replace? I am very new in VBA thought have to replace 1550 phrases asap for translation purpose.

Comment: try to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187909/word-vba-find-replace-issue) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609963/vba-to-find-and-replace-a-text-in-ms-word-2010) or [this](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) or [this](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/4-useful-methods-find-replace-text-part-word-document/). As you can see there are a lot of examples in Internet. Moreover, you could record a macro to get the code.